# Hilbert Space Inner Product

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let the sequences $(x_{n})$, $(y_{n})$ be two sets on the closed ball $B[0,1]$ in Hilbert Space, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle x_{n},y_{n}\rangle=1$.

Then show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|x_{n}-y_{n}\|=0$.

Can you give me a hint for this question?
How can I use that the sequences $(x_{n})$, $(y_{n})$ defined on B[0,1]?

Thank you..

Comment: The closed ball is complete so it ensures the existence of these limits. It may not have another use than to ensure the statement of the problem is rigorous.

Comment: Oh okay! So we can be sure that the limit exists thanks to the closed ball.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$\|x_n - y_n\|^2 = \|x_n\|^2 - 2 \langle x_n, y_n \rangle + \|y_n\|^2$$
then try to use the "squeeze theorem."

Comment: I will try it! Thank you.

Comment: Don't you need $\|x_n\|, \|y_n\| \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 1$ for this to work?
Because then: 
$$\|x_n - y_n\|^2 = \|x_n\|^2 - 2 \langle x_n, y_n \rangle + \|y_n\|^2\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 1 - 2 + 1 = 0$$

Comment: @mechanodroid It is sufficient to have $\|x_n\| \le 1$ and $\|y_n\| \le 1$ since then $0 \le \|x_n - y_n\|^2 \le 2 - 2 \langle x_n, y_n \rangle$. You can then note that $\|x_n\| \to 1$ and $\|y_n \| \to 1$ then happens automatically.

Comment: @angryavian Ah, you mean this:
$$1\xleftarrow{n\to\infty} |\langle x_n, y_n\rangle| \le \|x_n\| \|y_n\| \le 1$$

So by the squeeze theorem we conclude $\|x_n\|, \|y_n\| \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 1$.

Comment: @mechanodroid Sure, that works too.